# MobileFirst 7.0 network checking always fetched with "WIFI"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm following the javasript client side [API](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html%23getNetworkInfo) to do a detection of end-user network. The following code always seems to be fetched with a return value of "WIFI";

```
var netWorkType = "";
var isNWConnected = false;
WL.Device.getNetworkInfo(function (networkInfo) {
    isNWConnected = networkInfo.isNetworkConnected; //here, API seems to return a String value of "true" or "false" not boolean type
    netWorkType = networkInfo.networkConnectionType;
    if(isNWConnected == "true"){
        var str = "you are connecting with a " + netWorkType + " network";
        alert(str);
    } else {
        alert("NONE, checking your cellphone networking setting");
    }
});
```

On my iPhone 5s with iOS 8.4, 2G/3G or 4G carrier network return with "WIFI".

I don't know whether it's a bug of WL or maybe I'm doing somethin' wrong...

btw: MobileFirst 7.0 Server version: 7.0.0.00.20150312

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it indeed always returns wifi. This is a bug.

You'll need to open a PMR (support ticket) to have the development team investigate and provide a fix.

As a workaround you can use the Connection API provided by Cordova. I tested it and it returns the expected result:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_connection_connection.md.html

Comment: `cordova.exec(callback, callback, "NetworkDetector", "getNetworkInfo", [{}]);`  was found in file `worklight.js`  in iOS native folder, try to edit related plugin file `NetworkDetector` to do a workaround but it seems impossible as something is wrapped in `iphone\native\WorklightSDK\libWorklightStaticLibProject.a`

Comment: Yes, just don't use the WL.Device API for it until it is fixed; use the Cordova API as provided in their documentation.